# Unity sprite flying off map when rotating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am currently programming a game where the player must tilt their phone to rotate the world so they can navigate through a maze. This is proving difficult as when I rotate the phone the sprite flies off screen.
I am assuming this is to do with the forces between the character's and the world's colliders which ends up launching the character.
However, I want the character to have gravity follow the players relative down direction so that when the character rotates it falls the direction of its feet.

Therefore, **how should I rotate the direction of gravity to be relative to the sprite's direction and prevent the player from flying off when rotating?**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GyroController : MonoBehaviour {
    private Gyroscope Gyro ;
    private float rotation;
    private Vector3 startEulerAngles;
    private Vector3 startGyroAttitudeToEuler;
    public GameObject Player = null;

    private void Awake () {
        if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope) { 
            Gyro = Input.gyro;
            Gyro.enabled = false;
            startEulerAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
            startGyroAttitudeToEuler = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles;
            Debug.Log("Gyro Enabled");
        }
        else {
          Debug.Log("No Gyro Detected");
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 deltaEulerAngles = Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles - startGyroAttitudeToEuler;
        deltaEulerAngles.x = 0.0f;
        deltaEulerAngles.y = 0.0f;
        Player.transform.eulerAngles = startEulerAngles - deltaEulerAngles;
    }
}
```

So far I have only tried one method of changing the direction of gravity which involves moving the center of gravity which only made the character fall through other colliders. Hence, my gravity code is not included in this snippet.

**I am not asking for the code to be made for me, just a direction for me to look in as i've hit a dead end using rigidbody2d**

Thankyou.

Comment: Probably because you're rotating about the origin, and your sprite (not being at the origin) doesn't rotate with the world.

Comment: @Draco18s I don't want the world to rotate with the character. This is due to it being a game where as you tilt the device gravity changes direction so you can navigate a maze. Also, by rotating around the origin wouldn't this rotate the player massively rather than on the point is located?

Comment: You have to rotate the character with the world otherwise you will get strange side effects, like you're seeing (character phasing through walls/floors, or being strangely flung to one side). *`wouldn't this rotate the player massively`* Yes, and considering that that is the effect you described as happening....

Comment: Thankyou, i have managed to get this working after looking into rotating round itself rather than the world. and following on from this solved another problem i had in this method